# How do I use paintEvent to paint a QImage from video data?

Tags: c++, qt, paintevent

I construct a `QImage` with data I get from an API call. This `QImage` I will draw with the overridden `paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` method into a widget. From the function that does the API call I emit a signal that sends the grabbed data to a slot that constructs the `QImage`. With this process there is no problem. The data is transfered and the construct of the image works.

My question is how can I use the constucted image in the overridden paintEvent? I can open a image from the disk and draw it into the widget, but this works *from inside* the `paintEvent()` method. With the API call I got the data *from outside*.

```
class GrabberClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GrabberClass(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~GrabberClass();
    bool applyFrameCallback();
    bool getFrameData(DtMxData* data);
    bool startProcessing();
    
private:
    RenderClass *m_renderClass;
    DtMxProcess *m_process;
    DTAPI_RESULT m_result;
    DtFrame *m_Frame

signals:
    void sendFrameData(uchar* pData, int width, int height, int bytesPerRow);

};

//GrabberClass.cpp
//constructor
GrabberClass::GrabberClass(QObject *parent) :
    m_renderClass(new RenderClass)
{
   const bool connected = QObject::connect(this, &GrabberClass::sendFrameData, m_renderClass, &RenderClass::receiveFrameData, Qt::DirectConnection);
   Q_ASSERT(connected); //value is true.
}
        
bool GrabberClass::applyFrameCallback()
{
    auto frameCallback = [](DataContainer* frameData, void* pContext)
    {
        ((GrabberClass*)pContext)->getFrameData(frameData); 
    };
    
    m_result = m_process->AddMatrixCbFunc(frameCallback, this);
    if (m_result != DTAPI_OK) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool GrabberClass::grabFrame(DataContainer* frameData)
{   
    m_Frame = frameData->m_Rows[IN_ROW].m_CurFrame;
            
    uchar* pData = m_Frame->m_Video->m_Planes->m_pBuf;
    int bytesPerRow = m_Frame->m_Video->m_Planes->m_Stride;
    int frameWidth = m_Frame->m_Video->m_Width;
    int frameHeight = m_Frame->m_Video->m_Height;
            
    emit sendFrameData(pData, frameWidth, frameHeight, bytesPerRow);
            
    return true;
}
       

//Render Class.h
class RenderClass : public QOpenGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RenderClass(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~RenderClass();

private:
    QImage m_srcImage;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);

public slots:
    void receiveFrameData(uchar* pData, int width, int height, int bytesPerRow);
    
}; 

//RenderClass.cpp
VideoMonitor::VideoMonitor(QWidget* parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent),
    m_srcImage(nullptr)
{
}

void RenderClass::receiveFrameData(uchar* pData, int width, int height, int bytesPerRow) 
{
    m_srcImage = QImage(pData, width, height, bytesPerRow, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
            
    qDebug() << "Slot is called." << m_srcImage; //QImage is constructed with valid data
    QWidget::update();
}
            
void RenderClass::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    if (!m_srcImage.isNull()) { //m_srcImage is null
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawImage(this->rect(), m_srcImage);
        painter.end();
        qDebug() << "Draw image.";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "QImage is null";
    }
}
```

I'am new to C++, so it would be nice if someone of you can give me an advice and explaination.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve and the problems you've encountered -- preferably with a [mcve].  Also, does the code shown actually compile?

Comment: You should't call `QWidget::update` in each `paintEvent`. Better to call it from `receiveFrameData` to schedule repaint when image is available.

Comment: I updated the code above, but it is also reduced to the essential. My problem is that I did not understand how I can use a QImage that I create outside of the paint method. grabFrame is a Callback function that is called if a valid  frame is detected. The easiest way would be to use paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) as a slot, to send the data directly into function. But that is not possible.

Comment: @taathy 1) you receive the image data in the slot and save it to `m_srcImage`; 2) after that you call `QWidget::update` from this slot to schedule an asynchronous `paintEvent` call; 3) you use `m_srcImage` *inside* `paintEvent`. You shoudn't do any widget painting outside the paint event handler. But you already do something similar therefore I don't fully understand the problem. Perhaps, `m_srcImage` gets cleared before `paintEvent`?

Comment: @absolute.madness `paintEvent()` is called immediately by the starting the program. By pressing a button on the gui the slot gets the image data. So by starting the program it should be normal that the `m_srcImage` is null. But it didn't refresh after clicking the button. m_srcImage is implemented as private member. Not sure if this is a problem of Qt or a memory leak generally.

Comment: @taathy did you call `QWidget::update` after setting `m_srcImage` to schedule rapaint on step 2)?

Comment: @absolute.madness yes, I updated the code above. Theoretically `paintEvent()` should get the constructed image, but practically it didn't work.

Comment: @taathy if (a) `m_srcImage` is filled with the correct non-null data and (b) after that `paintEvent` is called and (c) in `paintEvent` image data is null again then logically *m_srcImage gets cleared before paintEvent*. It's hard to tell exactly when it happens without seeing the full code.

Comment: @absolute.madness I added further code. Do you mean with *m_srcImage gets cleared before paintEvent* that there is a memory leak?

Comment: You never initialize `GrabberClass::m_renderClass`.  In `GrabberClass::applyFrameCallback` what are `m_result` and `m_process`?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm surprised your app doesn't crash: since you connect `GrabberClass` to uninitialized `m_renderClass` in `GrabberClass::GrabberClass`. Also prefer using `Qt::AutoConnection` to `Qt::DirectConnection` unless you know what you're doing - when a signal is sent from another thread it may require synchronization.

Comment: I initialize m_renderClass in the constructor of `GrabberClass`. Befor I publish my code here I refactor the code to show only the essential code. Also I use `Qt::DirectConnect` because both classes runs in the same thread. And yes: The connection is working and the app did not crash.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a threading problem. I did not implement `QObject::connect` in the main class. After doing that, it works.